# Unable to access protocol methods via delegate

Tags: objective-c, swift, protocols

While accessing protocol methods via delegate I'm getting following error:
"No known instance method for selector 'lostConnection'"

Swift Protocol:

```swift
@objc protocol GameDelegate {
    func lostConnection()
}
```

Objective C game file

```Objective-c
//game.h

@protocol GameDelegate;
@interface SSStreamManager : NSObject 

@property (assign) id<GameDelegate> delegate

@end
```

Getting error while calling protocol methods

```Objetive-C
[self.delegate lostConnection]; // No known instance method for selector 'lostConnection'
```

Comment: "Getting error while calling protocol methods" Yes but you need to show the context in which you perform that call. Presumably it is in the _.m_ file for SStreamManager. That file needs to `#import` the Swift generated header, as you were already told in the comment on your other question.

Comment: I had the same issue try to delete DerivedData of Xcode (make sure your xcode is closed and when its deleted, open xcode). If it helped let me know. Path: `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

Comment: Deleted all derived data but still getting error as : No known instance method for selector 'lostConnection'

Comment: Also please show only real code. The code you are showing would never compile in the first place.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You haven't shown any real code, but here's an example that will get you started. These are the three files in an iOS app project:

*ViewController.swift*

```
import UIKit
@objc protocol GameDelegate {
    func lostConnection()
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
}
```

*Thing.h*

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@protocol GameDelegate;
@interface Thing : NSObject
@property (assign) id<GameDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

*Thing.m*

```
#import "Thing.h"
#import "MyApp-Swift.h"
@implementation Thing
- (void) test {
    [self.delegate lostConnection];
}
@end
```

That compiles. You should be able to follow this model in your own code.